# Firefox add-on: dynamic width for popups in menu

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

When a user moves a browserAction into the Firefox menu, it shrinks the available popup width, which can [break the display](https://github.com/EFForg/privacybadger/issues/1120) ...

[image: Privacy Badger popup broken in Firefox menu]

How do I dynamically size the popup width so it works in the Firefox menu?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `min-width` and `max-width` that works for the popup `body`, and then use `width: calc()`:

```
body {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```